# Url.Action to a post Action in a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a cshtml which is displaying a model:

```
           <div>
                    <h3>@WebMVCStrings.Title</h3>
                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title.Value)</span>
                </div>

                <div class="lead-summary__text">
                    <h3>@WebMVCStrings.Name</h3>
                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</span>
                </div>

                <div class="lead-summary__text">
                    <h3>@WebMVCStrings.Surname</h3>
                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Surname)</span>
                </div>
```

Then I have two button which should go to different actions in different controller.  My buttons are as follows:

```
   <div>

        <button id="createC">
            <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Back
        </button>

        <button id="createL">
           Submit
        </button>
    </div>
```

And I have javascript for both buttons:

```
<script>        
$("#createL").on("click", function (e) {
        window.location = "@Url.Action("CreateL", "LedController")&clientCode=@Model.ClientCode&ledId=0";
    });

    $("#createC").on("click", function (e) {
        window.location = "@Url.Action("CreateC", "ClientController", Model)";
    });
</script>
```

However when I click on the back button which is supposed to go to the CreateC action in the ClientController, it does not hit it.

My action CreateC is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateC(ClientViewModel clientViewModel)
    {*some actions*}
```

Any idea of how to do this?  Thanks

Comment: You cannot navigate to a POST method - you need to submit a form (and its not clear what you want to create since there are no form controls to submit data)

Comment: `window.location` loads page with GET request, not POST. The controller using `[HttpPost]` attribute so that it will not called. Use standard form posting with `BeginForm` and submit button instead.

Comment: Let me understand: clicking the button should POST to the specified controller actions? Changing `window.location` does not perform any post, it's another GET request. Add `[HttpGet]` or submit (manually or putting those `<button>` inside a `<form>`. It does not matter too much if outside `<form>` but default `<button>` type is `submit` then you should `preventDefault()` or simply specify `type="button"` if you're not using them to submit.

Comment: What does the method signature of the CreateL action look like? Is it the same as that of the CreateC action, expecting the same model class as a paramter?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: OK when I add the form to the CreateC action, the model gets only one property, the clientId which is a hidden in the cshtml.  The other properties are null.

Comment: If you do not have form controls for the other properties then they will be their defaults (a form only posts back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls. But what you are doing makes no sense - if there is nothing to edit, then what are you creating?

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  This page is displayed when the user clicks on an element of the list.  I need a back button to go back to this list which depends on some of the model properties.

Comment: Sorry, is not clear at all what you want to do. And why would you want a POST method, and send a model, if all you want is to redirect to the previous page

Comment: I know why I am getting the values as null, cause I am using DisplayFor.  So how can I display the previous page again?

Comment: Is CreateC an Action that changes data? If not, then it should not use POST and not require an AntiForgeryToken. Then you can easily navigate to it using GET. If CreateC changes data, then why would a back button execute it? A back button changing data is not what one would expect.